# Is this always the address for GDB debug program?

Tags: c++, gdb

I will narrow down my questions:

The entry address in GDB stays the same for the same program (even after reboot, and after rewriting the source code).

Why is that?

For example **0x80483f4** is the starting address.

```
**0x80483f4** <main()>              push   %ebp                                │
   │0x80483f5 <main()+1>            mov    %esp,%ebp                           │
   │0x80483f7 <main()+3>            sub    $0x10,%esp                          │
   │0x80483fa <main()+6>            movl   $0x3,-0x4(%ebp)                     │
   │0x8048401 <main()+13>           movl   $0x3,-0x8(%ebp)                     │
   │0x8048408 <main()+20>           mov    $0x0,%eax                           │
   │0x804840d <main()+25>           leave                                      │
   │0x804840e <main()+26>           ret
```

Beside that, the value we get from, let say, **0x80483fa**, is always the same.

```
$2 = 0x80483fa <main()+6>
(gdb) x $2
0x80483fa <main()+6>:   0x3fc45c7
(gdb) p 0x3fc45c7
$3 = 66864583   <-- even after reboot.
```

What does this suggest me?
I am interested in the values before and after each assignment (say c = a+b later), without using breakpoints to step through one line at a time.

The source code:

```
int main()
{ 
   int b = 3;
   int a = 3;
return 0;   
}
```

Can someone please explain this to me? Thanks. 
(I would also mark this as homework, although it really isn't.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example 0x80483f4 is the starting address.

This is likely. Unless you have PIE (position independent executables), it will stay the same (for one binary) forever.

> ```
> $2 = 0x80483fa <main()+6>
> (gdb) x $2
> 0x80483fa <main()+6>:   0x3fc45c7
> ```

That is the binary representation of the instructions at `main()+6`. Will never change in one binary.

> ```
> (gdb) p 0x3fc45c7
> $3 = 66864583   <-- even after reboot.
> ```

That means 0x3fc45c7 is 66864583 in decimal...

Note that none of this has anything to do with `a` or `b`.

BTW the best way to get values of variables "before assignment" is to `printf` them before the assignment.

Comment: without using the breakpoint, is there really a way to look into what value is stored in address 0x80483fa at this point? (well using breakpoint would mean I am in execution, and hence I can look up at the registers.) thanks jpalecek

Comment: you are right. however, I cannot use printf (or cout) directly from source code. I have to, use GDB to look into memory. I even tried other things such as ndisasm and hexdump. They only tell me the instructions.

Comment: You already have that value - it's 0x3fc45c7. But the address is wrong, it points to the code, not data.

Comment: BTW, `a` is an automatic variable, which lives on the stack, and not in the executable. Memory for it will only be allocated in `main()`.

Comment: you are right. When this program runs, it creates a stack frame. But this stack frame will vanished after execution. According to the code, it should allocate 16 bytes below ebp(decrement), right? So I should be able to find out where a SUPPOSED to live in, right?

Comment: Ah. If you just want the address of the variables, its `$ebp-4`. So either `x $ebp-4` or `p *(int*)($ebp-4)`. Or -8 for the other variable.

Comment: yes. but unfortunately, i cannot use these because they are not available (no breakpoint, afte execution registers and stacks are all cleaned). so commands like info locals, info registers will be no used. i opened a thread, and if you have time,may you give me your two cents?  :D    thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your program is (at least partially) statically linked, and `main()` almost certainly is. Rebooting your computer isn't going to change that statically linked part of the executable.

Comment: Static linking has nothing to do with *anything* here.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: Static linking has everything to do with the first question raised, which was "*The entry address in GDB stays the same for the same program (even after reboot, and after rewriting the source code).

Why is that?*" The address reported is a virtual address, not a physical address. That virtual address will not change without relinking the program.

Comment: @JohnWong: What is there to correct? There is nothing wrong here.