# Difference between gdb addresses and "real" addresses?

Tags: c++, c, gdb, hex, memory-address

If I run a C/C++ program in gdb (after compiling with the -g flag) and I examine the addresses of certain variables, arguments...etc, and then I run it outside of gdb (using `./`) will these addresses be the same as the ones I saw in gdb? If they're different are they usually similar or will they be drastically different?

I ask this because I have a buffer overflow program that works perfectly in gdb (with and without breakpoints), however when I try to run it outside of gdb it doesn't work.

Comment: Regarding your buffer overflow I recommend you try valgrind.

Comment: Force the program to core dump with "ulimit -c unlimited", then examine the core file with gdb.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I examine the addresses of certain variables, arguments...etc, and then I run it outside of gdb (using ./) will these addresses be the same as the ones I saw in gdb

It depends.

1. Global variables defined in the main executable will stay at the same address (unless the executable is built with `-fpie` and linked with `-pie` flags.
2. Global variables defined in other shared libraries may have drastically different addresses due to [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).
3. Local variables and parameters may move around by several K-bytes due to ASLR.
4. Heap-allocated variables may also drastically move due to ASLR, or if your program is multi-threaded.

Note that GDB on Linux by default disables ASLR, to make debugging easier. You can re-enable ASLR under GDB with `set disable-randomization off`. That may allow you to reproduce the problem under GDB.

> I have a buffer overflow

Also note, that tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [Address Sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) are often significantly more effective for finding buffer overflows than running under GDB. Address Sanitizer in particular is *great* in that it finds buffer overflows in globals and on stack (Valgrind doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

You should never ever assume that a certain code or vars will be located at a fixed place.

This was true in the past in the most OS but it is a security hole. malicious software uses this to inflect programs. OS will tend to scramble addresses to increase security.

Comment: I was just about to mention [address space layout randomization (ASLR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: One can *safely* assume that in a position-dependent executable, all global variables will stay at the same fixed address from one execution to another.

Comment: @ Employed Russian: I would not expect that. Why do you think so?

Comment: I don't *think*, I *know* (because I understand how executables get loaded into memory and how they are linked). Try it.

Comment: @stefanbachert: That's because the code refers to these addresses directly, and their memory is located in a special section of the PE (e.g. .data, .bss - depending on a few factors).

Answer (score 0):

Compiling with the `-g` flag increases the code size as it bungs into the executable extra information.

As to your buffer problem it would help to publish a snippet of code where things are going awry.

Comment: "Compiling with the -g flag increases the code size" -- no, it doesn't.